# Adding data in the form of LaTeX in xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, latex

In a typical situation where one adds initial data to a view controller in the form of words, how does one analogously implement data in the form of LaTeX and have it appear as math to the user (a.k.a when ran on the simulation)?

Comment: if the data is static, then you could just write the latex out into a pdf file then display it as a pdf in the app, otherwise maybe look if there is a library for iOS that does that sort of thing

Comment: whats the usual way of searching for ios libraries, are there any specific websites?

Comment: not that i know of... google :P